# How to make letters thickness on 3D picture constant

Tags: 3d, asymptote, acrobat

The following picture is drawn in Asymptote. In the first screenshot the letters look normal (Acrobat Reader's interactive viewing mode is disabled). In the second screenshot the letters look thicker (Acrobat Reader's interactive viewing mode is enabled).

**Question**: how to make them the same thickness, both before and after clicking on the interactive picture.

**Clarification**: right after clicking on the interactive picture (to activate interactive viewing mode), letters look thicker.

[image]
[image]

The complete .tex file for generating the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.render=20;
import solids;
currentprojection = perspective(0,100,25);
viewportmargin=(0.1cm,0.1cm);
unitsize(1cm);
triple pO=(0,0,0);
label("$A$",X,W);
label("$B$",0*X,W);
dot((0,0,0));
dot((0,0,1));

\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Is this related to asymptote, or do you make the same observation for any document?

Comment: @mickep this is related to asymptote, because this is the case in any PDF-document, when I put an Asymptote's picture in it.

Comment: @mickep by the way, the screenshots were taken of the same document (before and after enabling of Acrobat Reader's interactive viewing mode)

Comment: So I take it as if you do not use asymptote then you do not see this? (That is the logic I was after.)

Comment: @mickep well, if I don't use asymptote, I am not able to enable Acrobat Reader's interactive viewing mode. The thing is, only asymptote allows to obtain interactive pictures, to my knowledge. This is 3D pictures, of course.

Comment: one short clarification, right after clicking on the interactive picture, letters look thicker